# How many handshakes for parallel http connection?

Tags: tcp

HTTP uses TCP for its transport protocol. Hence, a three-way handshake is performed before a connection is established. What if there are parallel HTTP connections? Must a three-way handshake must be performed for each connection or will one suffice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, parallel HTTP connections requires separate three-way handshakes.

Multiple HTTP requests can be handled in one TCP connection. This can happen sequentially, but since HTTP/1.1, the concept of pipelining allows sending multiple HTTP requests in one TCP connection without waiting for the responses. This results in a seemingly parallel handling of HTTP requests, but note HTTP/1.1 requires the server to send the responses sequentially and in the same order as it received the corresponding requests.